# Fitting truncated and censored data

Tags: python, fitting, interval-censoring, truncated-distributions

I have data that is truncated on the left and censored on the right. The reason is that this is claims data, which for a claim gives the amount of the claim. The claim appears in the data:

- Only if it exceeds a reporting threshold $\alpha$ (which is known) ;
- If the amount exceeds a limit amount $\beta$ (which is known), then this amount $\beta$ is shown (instead of the true amount).

My goal is to find the best distribution among a set of distributions (exponential, gamma, beta, lognormal, normal, weibull, loglogistic, pareto, generalized pareto, etc.) according to a certain method (MME or MLE) and certain estimation criteria (SSE, etc.).

1. Assume that $\beta=+\infty$ (i.e. no censoring). Does fitting a distribution or the equivalent truncated distribution gives the same result? I suppose not, but I don't really have any intuition about this.
2. Let's assume $\beta<+\infty$ . Here it's very clear that the result will be different between original and censored distributions. But I don't really know how to make a censored distribution.
3. So far I use the python library Fitter, but it does not allow to fit truncated or censored distributions. Is there another library (python, R or other) that allows to do this? I'd rather avoid having to implement all these fits myself.

Comment: I presume *"then this amount is shown"* means *"then the amount $\beta$ is shown"*? Could you please edit the question to make that unambiguous?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Stef it's done!

Comment: The R package [fitdistrplus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) can fit to censored data. I don't know if there's a Python equivalent.